# python3 List with .sort() goes wrong

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

Im trying to sort a list in Python 3 using Visual Studio Code:
I take my list from the arguments in the commandline. The first argument is ignored that's my needle variable.
After adding all variables in the lost I want to sort the list.
The problem is that it gets sorted in a rather strange way

after 2 comes 21 and then 3 after 5 comes 55 and than 6

This is my commandline:

```
C:\Users\Gebruikertje\Desktop\Python>python find.py 21 2 3 4 5 6 21 55 3
```

this is the output:

```
['2', '21', '3', '3', '4', '5', '55', '6']
```

This is the part of the code im referring to

```
import sys

finish = len(sys.argv)
needle = sys.argv[1]
haystack = []
for i in range (2,finish ):
    haystack.append(sys.argv[i])
haystack.sort()
print(haystack)
```

Comment: you are sorting a list of strings (not integers), try `haystack.sort(key = lambda x: int(x))` or just make your list integers to begin with

Comment: This is because the numbers are strings. Try the same code with integers.

Comment: @Chris_Rands umm... that could just be `key=int`...

Comment: @JonClements Whoops yep agreed, but they probably actually don't want a list of strings initially

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to sort a list of strings.

Convert them to **int** while adding them to **list**.

```
haystack.append(int(sys.argv[i]))
```

You can also use [`map()`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html) here:

```
haystack = map(int, sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.
That was exactly the problem. One step forward in the world of Python

Answer (score 1):

The values inputed from `argv` are strings, and thus are sorted lexicographically. You should convert them to numbers if you wan to sort them numerically. Doing this in a list comprehension could also help clean up some boiler plate from your loop:

```
haystack = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]]
haystack.sort()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
x = ['2', '21', '3', '3', '4', '5', '55', '6']
y = [int(number) for number in x]
y.sort()

# Result = [2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 21, 55]
```